# How does Amazon Dynamodb transaction work under the hood?

Tags: transactions, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

[Amazon DynamoDB has recently announced transaction](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/). I am interested to know how this transaction works under the hood for a NoSQL storage like dynamodb - how does it differ from traditional relational database in terms of mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

First, traditional relational databases have two transaction mechanisms: locks and versions.

Quote from the blog:

> DynamoDB performs two underlying reads or writes of every item in the transaction, one to prepare the transaction and one to commit the transaction.

As I understand it, this means that versions of the data are created. Therefore, the DynamoDB mechanism similar to RDBMS versioning.